# Fetch request with token in Header

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I need help to include token in the header when I'm doing fetch request on address 'http://localhost:8080/clients'.

Right now I'm getting this message "HTTP 403 Forbidden".

**Authorization Token 1234abcd**

```
function getAllClients() {
      const myHeaders = new Headers();
      myHeaders.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');

      return fetch('http://localhost:8080/clients', {
        method: 'GET',
        mode: 'no-cors',
        headers: myHeaders,
      })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then((user) => {
          console.log(user.name);
          console.log(user.location);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.error(error);
        });
    }

    getAllClients();
```

Comment: Have you tried appending the token with the header? Give some more info on the API you have created and how the token needs to be called.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

With `fetch()`, you cannot send `Authorization` header when the `no-cors` mode is enabled.

> no-cors — Prevents the method from being anything other than HEAD, GET
> or POST, and the headers from being anything other than simple
> headers.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request/mode

What are simple headers?

- `Accept`
- `Accept-Language`
- `Content-Language`
- `Content-Type` and whose value, once extracted, has a MIME type (ignoring parameters) that is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`,
  `multipart/form-data`, or `text/plain`

https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#simple-header

So your problem is in the following line:

```
mode: 'no-cors',
```

Just drop it from the fetch request and append your `Authorization` header as usual.

```
const myHeaders = new Headers();

myHeaders.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
myHeaders.append('Authorization', '1234abcd');

return fetch('http://localhost:8080/clients/', {
  method: 'GET',
  headers: myHeaders,
})
```

Answer (score 6):

There are multiple methods you can set the header in the request, you can check the documentation [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Headers).

Here is updated code:

```
function getAllClients() {
const myHeaders = new Headers({
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': 'your-token'
});

return fetch('http://localhost:8080/clients', {
  method: 'GET',
  headers: myHeaders,
})

.then(response => {
    if (response.status === 200) {
      return response.json();
    } else {
      throw new Error('Something went wrong on api server!');
    }
  })
  .then(response => {
    console.debug(response);
  }).catch(error => {
    console.error(error);
  });
}

getAllClients();
```

Answer (score 3):

Well this is what you need :

```
 function getAllClients() {
  const myHeaders = new Headers();

  /* 
    myHeaders.append('Content-Type', 'application/json'); 
    since it's a get request you don't need to specify your content-type
  */

  myHeaders.append('Authorization', 'Token 1234abcd');

  return fetch('http://localhost:8080/clients', {
    method: 'GET',
    mode: 'no-cors',
    headers: myHeaders,
  })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then((user) => {
      console.log(user.name);
      console.log(user.location);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error(error);
    });
}

getAllClients();
```

Comment: This was very helpful, but just without "mode: 'no-cors',". Thanks Fabien